# Chrome flags my SSL

Tags: apache, https, openssl

Chrome keeps on showing me yellow triangle, 4 days ago padlock was green. I reissued the certificate and every ssl check test i found passed. **Domain is buzztera.gr**, do you guy know any other tool i can use ? Certificate is SHA-2. I use Apache for hosting and generated the keys with openssl using the following commands

```
openssl genrsa -out key_name.key 4096
openssl req -out CSR.csr -key key_name.key -new -sha256
```

yes i know i don't need to use 4096, but if i can why not ?
Apache Logs show no error.

Answer (score 1):

There's two reasons for the Chrome browser showing the yellow warning icon associated with your security status:

1. Certificate strength (and algorithm used);
2. Mixed content warnings - serving HTTP over HTTPS

A good test to check #1 is the [Qualys SSL Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

Chrome developer tools will show if there's any insecure content for #2.

When I checked the URL you gave, I got the all-green.

Comment: exactly, all green.. no mixed content and strength is 4096